# Why is the message echoing?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So here's the part I'm having an issue with

```
//Post 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];   
$password = $_POST['password']; 
$password1 = $_POST['passworconf'];

//Verifcation 
if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) ||    empty($password1))
{
echo "Complete all fields";

}
```

And what happens is its supposed to check if everything is entered. But I still get the message `Complete all fields` even though they're all filled. Any ideas?

Comment: Do `var_dump($_POST)` and post the results in your question

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you missed a `d` letter here? `$_POST['passworconf'];`

you can use mozilla firefox and install firebug addon. on firebug open "net" you will see there are some post request . on these request try to see what is your mistake